# Ardiuno : Servo Connected to a Button

Tags: arduino

I am new to Arduino and trying to just create a simple application so a servo goes forward 50 degrees when a button is pushed(not continuous) and when let go of it will go back 50 degrees. For some reason my servo just keeps running. What should I do to debug this.

```
#include <Servo.h>

Servo myservo; // creating myservo object
int buttonPin = 2;
int servoPin = 3;
int buttonState = 0; // set buttonState 

void setup()
{
myservo.attach(servoPin); 
pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT); 
}


void loop()
{ buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin); // read and save to the variable "buttonState" the actual state of button
if (buttonState == HIGH)
myservo.write(50); else
myservo.write(0);

}
```

[image][image][image]

Comment: What do you mean by keep running? it doesn't stop at 50 degrees?

Comment: no it just keeps going 360 and won't stop

Comment: What kind of servo is this?

Comment: Yeah that's not a servo, it's doing exactly what the code says to do given a normal DC motor. Try it with an actual servo. You may also get a better answer over on http://robotics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You said it's not a continuous servo.  Yet you say it goes 360.   A normal position-seeking hobby servo is literally not mechanically capable of that.  So you're wrong about the servo type.  And all switches need to be debounced either in hardware or software.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [Bounce library](http://www.arduino.cc/playground/Code/Bounce) library to catch the edge's you are looking for. Your script as written is continuously updating the PWM with 50 or 0. It is never getting a chance to actually do it. Hence you only want to update it on a change; either depress or release.

I have not tested the below. It does compile and is a simple hack from the examples and your above.

```
#include <Servo.h>
#include <Bounce.h>

#define BUTTON 2
#define servoPin 3
#define LED 13

Servo myservo;  // create servo object to control a servo
Bounce bouncer = Bounce( BUTTON, 5 );

void setup() {
  pinMode(BUTTON,INPUT);
  pinMode(LED,OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
  myservo.attach(servoPin);
}

void loop() {

  if ( bouncer.update() ) {
    if ( bouncer.fallingEdge()) {
      myservo.write(50);
      digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
    } else if ( bouncer.risingEdge()) {
      myservo.write(0);
      digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
    }
  }
  // foo bar...
}
```

Comment: myservo.attach(servoPin); gives servo:14: error: expected `)' before ';' token

Comment: Most Arduino's have a LED on D13. And it is common to use it for quick diagnostics. Here it will start off with the LED ON, and when you depress the button on D2 it the LED(D13) will turn off and back on when you release. This way you have some diagnostic as to whether or not the code is actually setting the Servo's speed. So if the LED does what it is supposed to and the Servo does not, then it is not a problem with the code. but rather the servo or wiring.

Comment: my bad about the error: I accidentally posted bad code. I have updated the answer with code the correct code/example.

Comment: You should not necessarily use a library.  There are many ways to debounce a switch.  Using a bloated and wasteful library is only one way.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to take a wild guess that you have a continuous rotation servo. These servos have the position feedback from the potentiometer removed/disconnected so when you apply any rotation to the servo it will continuously spin thinking that it is not yet at the desired position. These servos have three control positions: off (likely 90 degrees) clockwise (anything larger than 90) and counterclockwise (anything less than 90). Some do allow you to control speed as well (I think the VEX one you cite having may be one - look up the spec sheet).

I might have my no movement value wrong (it may not be 90) and my counter/clockwise reversed, but I am almost certain this is your issue. Basically your motor is not what you think it is :)

Answer (score 0):

```
myServo.writeMicroseconds(1500);
```

This will make it stop if its not broken and its a continuous digital servo.